# How to record all calls and auto-sync to Dropbox?

Tags: dropbox, call-recording

I just installed [Automatic Call Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appstar.callrecorder&hl=en), which almost does as I ask - it can auto-record all calls. But it stores them to an "inbox" on the device, and deletes old items when the inbox is filled.

I'd like to auto-record any call and then auto-sync every call to Dropbox. How can I achieve this? I would also like to know the disk space it takes.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this from the app you are currently using. Go to the settings and click the dropbox link which can be found under *Cloud*. Make sure you have installed Dropbox and you're connected to the internet.

[image: Automatic Call Recorder]
<sup>*Image: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appstar.callrecorder&hl=en). Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYMW4.png) for a larger variant.*</sup>

There are other options such as [Call Recorder with DropBox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=call.record.freedp) as well.

Comment: I don't think it does that. I did enable Dropbox integration, but uploading a recording to Dropbox is manual, I can't simply tell it to upload *all* recordings to Dropbox.

Comment: @ripper234 Did you try the other alternative I have mentioned?

Comment: Not yet, haven't had the time.

Answer (score 0):

Use any application you want for recording your calls!

Use an app like [DropSpace](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kr.pe.meinside.DropSpace&hl=en) to set up sync lists, mark your recording directory and voila you are done and set to go like a BOSS :D

Answer (score 0):

I know this comes way late, but try [Dropsync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.dropsync&hl=en), which syncs to Dropbox automatically - rather more the way Dropbox' desktop app works than its mobile app does. It can sync on a schedule or continuously watch files for changes and sync on any change. I use the pro version and can recommend it as having been reliable and trouble free.